# C++ Sorting strings by size and alphabet

Tags: c++, string, sorting, string-length, alphabetical

So I have to sort an array of strings primarily by size which works without any problem.
Then I try to alphabetically sort those of the same size in a similar way and to put it simply it comes out as complete mess.

Code part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct strs{
    string str;
    int sz; //stores size of the string
};

bool compare(string a, string b, int s){ //comparing by characters
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        if(a[i] > b[i]) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(){
    int n, chk;
    bool ctr;

    cin>>n;

    strs tab[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>tab[i].str;

        tab[i].sz = tab[i].str.size();
    }

    //Comparing lengths
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        chk = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){

            if(tab[chk].sz > tab[j].sz){
                chk = j;
            }
        }

        if(chk != i){
            swap(tab[i].str, tab[chk].str);
            swap(tab[i].sz, tab[chk].sz);
        }
    }

    //Comparing characters
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        chk = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){

            if(tab[chk].sz == tab[j].sz){

                ctr = compare(tab[chk].str, tab[j].str, tab[chk].sz);
                if(ctr) chk = j;

            }

            if(tab[i].sz < tab[j].sz) break;
        }

        if(chk != i){
            swap(tab[i].str, tab[chk].str);
            swap(tab[i].sz, tab[chk].sz);
        }
    }

    //output
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<tab[i].str<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And to show what I mean by "mess" (copying from console) for input:

- chair
- mouse
- angle
- wreck
- angel

The output looks like this:

- angel
- chair
- mouse
- angle
- wreck

So it's nothing close to being sorted and I have no idea what different way I could try to make it work.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::sort`?

Comment: Kindly show real code that actually compiles and produces the undesired results which are as you describe. The shown code will not compile due to an obvious typo in the very middle of the code. Although the overall logical error in your sorting algorithm seems rather obvious, the nature of the typo (not a fat-finger) strongly suggests that this is not the real code you are using, but an edited/garbled/truncated version; and, as such, any attempted explanation will likely be moot, since this is not the real code being compiled, and executed.

Comment: Yes I can use std::sort. And I copy pasted code again as indeed compare function had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare function should be something like:

```
bool compare(const std::string& a, const std::string& b, int s){ //comparing by characters
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]) return a[i] > b[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

but simpler is using `std::sort`:

```
auto proj = [](const std::string& s){ return std::make_tuple(s.size(), std::ref(s)); };
auto compare = [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs);
};

std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), compare);
```